# Setting the labels of colorbar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have spent a couple hours trying to figure this out. I want the colorbar to display three values along the bar, [0, 3315/2, 3315]. However, I am just getting this result:

[image]

Code:

```
print(max(average_powers)) # 3314.455810547
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])
mn=int(np.floor(0)) 3 
mx=int(np.ceil(max(average_powers)))
md=(mx-mn)/2
cb = plt.colorbar(sm)
cb.set_ticks([mn,md,mx])
cb.set_ticklabels([mn,md,mx],update_ticks=True)
cb.set_label('Magnitude of Average Power for turbine')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this [matplotlib demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html) help?

Comment: Just stopping by to say that your chart is gorgeous!

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
cb.set_ticks([mn,md,mx])
```

With

```
cb.set_ticks([0, 0.5, 1])
```